# Pull the latest changes from git for a specifc repository

Tags: git, bash, github, azure-devops, git-bash

I have written an automated script using vsts personal access token to clone all the repositories in a project to my local. The script is

```
repoPaths=('repo1Url','repo2Url',etc...)
for i in "${repoPaths[@]}"
do
     git clone $repPaths[i] $localPath
done
```

Now, I'm trying to make some changes in the above bash script to pull the latest changes if the clone is **available** from *all of the repo's*.

Please suggest.

Comment: When you run `git clone`, you get the latest changes at that moment.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by 'the clone is available' with an example perhaps ?

Comment: @Ashutosh Jindal : when you run the script the first time then the clone is created, now say I make some changes to local, now if I run the script again I want to merge my local changes with the latest, currently this is not implemented.

Comment: You're looking for [`git pull`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)?

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 steps, one to pull all repos in x directory and one to clone all repos in x directory. Something like this should suffice:

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull origin master \;
```

So combined, it'd be:

```
find . -type d -depth 1 -exec git --git-dir={}/.git --work-tree=$PWD/{} pull origin master \;
repoPaths=('repo1Url','repo2Url',etc...)
for i in "${repoPaths[@]}"
do
     git clone $repPaths[i] $localPath
done
```

*Note: This will result in some errors that look like `fatal: destination path 'repo1Url' already exists and is not an empty directory.` if it already exists*